# Как фильтровать данные?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Получаю из базы все книги а сервер отдает их клиенту

Подскажите каким образом выводить ( популярные, новые и.т.д )

Есть способ как то фильтровать все книги на фронте ? или же делать отдельные запросы к серверу и там сортировать в mysql?

Comment: Даже не знаю какой ответ ожидается, но первое что приходит в голову: "Да, способы фильтровать данные на клиенте есть".

Comment: Фильтровать надо на сервере и не тянуть лишние данные, нагружая сеть и оперативку. Чем ближе к sql-серверу фильтровка (в идеале - на нём самом, хуже - на бекенде, самый худший сценарий - на клиенте) тем лучше.